# Timeseries yearly boxplot with TimeGrouper : ValueError

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, time-series

I am trying to represent yearly box splot with TimeGrouper

```
from pandas import Series
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import TimeGrouper
from matplotlib import pyplot
series = Series.from_csv('test4.csv', header=0)
groups = series.groupby(TimeGrouper('A'))
years = DataFrame()
for name, group in groups:
    years[name.year] = group.values
years.boxplot()
pyplot.show()
```

(I generate csv from Excel)

My csv dataset is very simple, 2 columns

```
Date,Temp
01/01/81,8447
....
```

When I try with [test4-ok.csv](http://easymagic-secret.fr/codes/test4-ok.csv), my box splot appears.

If I take the same data but with others range dates [test4-ko.csv](http://easymagic-secret.fr/codes/test4-ko.csv),

```
Date,Temp
01/01/09,8447
....
```

I have the following errors

**ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index**

What is the problem with test4-ko.csv ?

Thank you for your help

Olivier

Answer (score 1):

I just found an issue... When TimeGrouper('A') is used, dataset must have exactly 365 days per year... but with leap years, some years of my dataset have 366 days...
You have just to delete one row (one day) per leap year.